# will_paginate ajax with fade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination, prototypejs

I'm trying to ajaxify my will_pagniate pagination in rails. I want to have the old page fade out and the new one fade in.

Here's the relevant part of my controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.js {
    render :update do |page|
      page.replace 'page', :partial => 'cur_page'
    end
  }
  format.xml  { render :xml => @branch }
end
```

The aforementioned partial:

```
<div id="page">
  <%= will_paginate %>
  <div id="posts">
    <%= render @posts %>
  </div>
  <%= will_paginate %>
</div>
```

And the relevant part of application.js:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  // the element in which we will observe all clicks and capture
  // ones originating from pagination links
  var container = $(document.body)

  if (container) {
    var img = new Image
    img.src = '/images/spinner.gif'

    function createSpinner() {
      return new Element('img', { src: img.src, 'class': 'spinner' })
    }

    container.observe('click', function(e) {
      var el = e.element()
      if (el.match('.pagination a')) {
        el.up('.pagination').insert(createSpinner())
        target = $('posts')
        new Effect.fade(target, { duration: 0.3, afterFinish: function()
          {
            new Ajax.Request(el.href,
            {
              method: 'get',
              onSuccess: function(){ new Effect.Appear(target, {duration:0.3})}
            })
        }})
        e.stop()
      }
    })
  }
})
```

The script seems to get killed on this line,

```
        new Effect.fade(target, { duration: 0.3, afterFinish: function()
```

because I see the spinner.gif start, then no fading and the page is refreshed normally. I have got the ajax working before I tried to add Effect.Fade and Effect.Appear.

Is this the right way to go about this? Should I put the effects in the controller instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is what I did using `jQuery` and working well too :)

Put your `will_paginate` helper view call in a div

```
#tickets_pagination
  = will_paginate @tickets
```

In application.js

```
$("#tickets_pagination .pagination a").live("click", function() {
  $.get("/users/?"+this.href.split("?")[1], null, null, "script");
  return false
});
```

The javascript above will convert the pagination links in `#tickets_pagination` to ajax links

In your controller as usual

```
def index
  @tickets = Ticket.all.paginate({:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10 })
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html
  end
end
```

Now finally in index.js.erb

```
$("#tickets_list_table").fadeOut('slow');
$("#tickets_list_table").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial =>'tickets/tickets_table', :locals => {:tickets => @tickets}) %>");
$("#tickets_list_table").fadeIn('slow');
```

Here `tickets/ticket_table` has a table that lists all tickets. The partial is rendered in a div `#ticket_list_table`

Hope this will work for you as well.

Comment: Unfortunately this introduces a weird effect, at least for me anyways. The Ajax page loads, then fades out, and then fades back in.

Answer (score 2):

I tried putting more of the work into the javascript helpers:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.js {
    render :update do |page|
      page.visual_effect :fade, 'posts', :afterFinsh => "function(){" +
      page.replace 'page', :partial => 'cur_page' +
      page.visual_effect(:appear, 'branches') + "}"
    end
  }
  format.xml  { render :xml => @branch }
end
```

Then removed this part of the javascript:

```
new Effect.fade(target, { duration: 0.3, afterFinish: function()
```

I get the effect I want, but all out of order. The request completes and the html is replaced, **then** the div fades out and then reappears!

Answer (score 1):

Not very familiar with RoR, does it generate its own client-side JS that may possibly be battling your code?

If not, I would say the problem is somewhere in your own client-side code.  For testing, get rid of the HREF attribute from the anchor tag and place the URL as a string literal in the Ajax request.  If nothing happens, there is a problem with the Ajax request itself.  If the page loads as expected, then the event in the original scenario is not being completely stopped.

Also, clean up your JS a bit just to be sure, line-ending semi-colons where needed.

Comment: It works when I comment out the part: new Effect.fade(target, { duration: 0.3, afterFinish: function(), so something is wrong with that. I added semicolons but I got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to mix up things a bit.
Either you write `$('posts').fade` or `new Effect.fade('posts')`.

Secondly, i can't seem to find the `afterFinish` option in the [documentation](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/effect-fade/).

So i would suggest something along the following lines:

```
container.observe('click', function(e) {
  var el = e.element()
  if (el.match('.pagination a')) {
    el.up('.pagination').insert(createSpinner())
    target = $('posts')
    new Effect.fade('posts', { duration: 0.3});
    setTimeout("new Ajax.Request(el.href, { method: 'get', 
          onSuccess: function(){ 
            new Effect.Appear('posts', {duration:0.3}) 
          } })", 1000);
    e.stop();
  }
})
```

Hope this helps.